# Vimeo Slider Script - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error

I am using a script I found on a forum to tie into the Vimeo API with my javascript slider but I am getting an error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

It says that the error exists on this line:

```
var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
```

And here's the whole script:

```
(function () {

    var $=jQuery;


    var f = $('iframe');
    var url = f.attr('src').split('?')[0]; <?php //HACK! had to hard code the protocol in here or postMethod shows error: Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified. ?>
    //var status = $('.status');


    // Listen for messages from the player
    if (window.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
    }

    // Handle messages received from the player
    function onMessageReceived(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);


        switch (data.event) {
            case 'ready':
                onReady();
                break;

            case 'playProgress':
                onPlayProgress(data.data);
                break;

            case 'pause':
                onPause();
                break;

            case 'finish':
                onFinish();
                break;
        }
    }

    // Call the API when a button is pressed
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        post($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });

    // Helper function for sending a message to the player
    function post(action, value) {
        var data = { method: action };

        if (value) {
            data.value = value;
        }
        $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);
    }

    function onReady() {


        post('addEventListener', 'pause');
        post('addEventListener', 'finish');
        post('addEventListener', 'playProgress');
    }

    function onPause() {
        console.log("vimeo paused");
    }

    function onFinish() {
        playing = setInterval(function() {slide('left')}, 6000);
        console.log("vimeo finish");
        slide('left');
    }

    function onPlayProgress(data) {
        clearInterval(playing);
        console.log("vimeo play progress");
    }
})();
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this code:
var f = $('iframe');

If you've got other iframes on your page, the code will target those. It's probably a facebook like/share button which is what it was in my case. You've got to fill the f variable with something like this:

var f = $('.vimeoplayer');

Even with that though, I still ran into problems. I don't think using plain javascript/jquery to interact with the vimeo player is feasible without using their mini-library: "froogaloop." I started using froogaloop and it solved all my problems. Froogaloop is only a few lines of code ... totally worth it.

http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api